# PDO not returning an object, but an array

Tags: php, pdo

With the following code, PDO won't return my $parcel as an object, but as an array. There for when i try to call my objects function, it will fail. Every example i have found has done this, in a similar way to mine. What am i doing wrong?

```
    $statement = $this->connection->query($query);

    $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Parcel');

    while ($parcel = $statement->fetch()) {
        echo $parcel->hello();
    }
```

The Parcel class, if interested.

```
class Parcel {
public $id;
public $parcel_number;
public $registred_at;
public $shipped_by;
public $shipped_at;

function __construct($parcel_number)
{
    $this->parcel_number = $parcel_number;
}

public function hello(){
    return "World";
}
}
```

And im using folder structures to structure the code and an Autoloader, that can probaly affect the PDO's way of calling the object.

While this is the error code

```
Call to a member function info() on a non-object
```

Comment: For interests sake, could you show what `print_r($parcel)` (in your while loop) returns?

Comment: Or, better yet, what does `var_dump($parcel)` say?

Comment: array(10) { ["id"]=> string(1) "8" [0]=> string(1) "8" ["parcel_number"]=> string(4) "post" [1]=> string(4) "post" ["registred_at"]=> string(19) "2014-08-03 14:19:50" [2]=> string(19) "2014-08-03 14:19:50" ["shipped_by"]=> NULL [3]=> NULL ["shipped_at"]=> NULL [4]=> NULL } ... n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means the object is null or not instantiated properly, you might need to specify full path to your class.

For example

```
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'app\model\Parcel');
```